# Serilog: Prevent Empty Log File Creation

Tags: c#, .net-core, configuration, serilog

**EDIT:** The below accepted answer works *partially*. It does defer file creation, but it does not respect a minimum `LogEventLevel` (since the deferred line is called whenever logging occurs, even if it ends up not writing to the file). It does, however, accomplish my overarching goal of "no blank file creation" (and I will just log errors in my application), so I'm keeping it as the accepted answer.

My final code looks like this:

```
new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.Map("", "", (_, writeTo) => writeTo.File("SampleName.log")).CreateLogger();
```

---

I have a simple console application in which I'm using Serilog and a File sink:

```
new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.File("SampleName.log", LogEventLevel.Error).CreateLogger();
```

Ideally, I would only want it to create a log file on disk when there is something to log (errors in my scenario). However, if the application runs and completes without errors, Serilog will still create an empty file. Is there a way to instruct Serilog to **only** create a file when it has something to log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible as of this writing. [The file is created on disk as soon as the `FileSink` instance is created](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Sinks.File/Sinks/File/FileSink.cs#L75) and there's no configuration option to change that behavior.

You could create a sink that wraps the `FileSink` and *lazily* create the `FileSink` instance whenever the first log event is emitted.

Or, you could delete the empty file at the end, just before your app ends (but after you call `Log.CloseAndFlush`).

Comment: @RubenBartelink Good thinking. `Serilog.Sinks.Map` probably works given it creates the sink at the time of emitting the log events. /cc @DoctorBlue

Comment: Definitely going to check out Map ( https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-map ) next time I'm available! Looks like just the thing I need and will save the trouble of making a lazy sink wrapper.

Comment: @DoctorBlue One other thing you might consider (assuming what's bothering you is having the empty file alongside the `.exe` of your app), is to store the log file somewhere else e.g. `%localappdata%\yourapp\yourapp.log` so it's always out of sight... That's what I usually do with my apps given I only check the logs on occasion when troubleshooting something... `Serilog.Sinks.Map` is super cool and very useful to map specific properties to sinks, but I personally would not take the overhead of `Serilog.Sinks.Map` in my logging pipeline just for the sake of not having an empty log file.

Comment: @CaioProiete I'd absolutely squirrel them away, but circumstances around this particular requirement prevent me from doing so.